# Changing your production source code location

Tags: java, gradle

According to the gradle user guide: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide.pdf top of page 41 "Gradle expects to find your production source code under src/main/java".  How can I customize gradle to use with my current and different directory structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Gradle docs regarding [source sets](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:source_sets). You can specify your source directory like so:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'path/to/java/src'
        }
    }
}
```